# How to access IBoutlet of one view controller in another view controller using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I change the label text to textfield text?
This source code change the label text to textfield text which are in the same class, but I want to change the label in different class.
label is in the ViewController.swift and textfield is in the ProfileViewController.swift

This is the source code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var hedgeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var hideView: UIView!
    var sideBar:SideBar = SideBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }
```

ProfileViewController.swift

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ouput: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBAction func nameChange(sender: AnyObject) {
        ouput.text = name.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many ways to do this: You can add an observer to textField and update a variable that holds the name text which then you can send to the new vc in prepare for segue. Here is a sample

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var nameRecieved:String?
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!{
        didSet{
            if nameRecieved != nil { name.text = nameRecieved }
        }
    }
}

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var nameHolder:String?
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField! { didSet{ name.delegate = self } }
    //notification    
    var nameTextFieldObserver: NSObjectProtocol?
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        let q = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        nameTextFieldObserver = center.addObserverForName(UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: name, queue: q){
            notification in
            self.nameHolder = self.name.text
        }
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if nameTextFieldObserver != nil { NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(nameTextFieldObserver!) }
    }

    //Here you can pass the value of nameHolder to the other vc's var nameRecieved in your prepare for segue 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help I solve the problem using prepareforsegue function:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch hold on to your `ViewController` object and pass the values. Something like this:

```
@IBAction func nameChange() {
    ouput.text = name.text

    // given both your views have a same parent
    // and this view is the first child
    let myViewController = parentViewController!.childViewControllers[1]

    myViewController.name.text = name.text
    myViewController.printLabelText()
}
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to change a view from another view controller? I think this is against MVC principles. `delegate`s are there for this exact purpose.

Comment: You may have two view controllers showing side by side on your screen. Here we are not switching from one VC to another VC on change of text in text field in one of the VC. Assuming both VC are on visible on screen, changing text in text field of once VC is changing the label on another VC. If second VC is not on screen then shared data would be visible once second VC is appeared on screen.